# Self locked out for writing to a partition in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, permissions

In Windows 7, I changed the permissions to access a ntfs partition for all four user groups (Autenticated Users, SYSTEM, Administrators (ADMIN\Administrators), and Users (ADMIN\Users)) to allow only three options "Read & execute", "List folder contents", and "Read".
This is done by right clicking on the partition and select `Properties`, and in the security tab click `Edit` to change the permissions. I learned it from Dave Rook's reply to my earlier [question](https://superuser.com/questions/473214/how-to-make-a-ntfs-partition-on-internal-hdd-read-only-and-later-writable). (Thanks, Dave!)

Now I want to change back to be able to write into that partition, but I find I am not allowed to edit the permissions including the `Add` being grayed out, probably because my account is allowed for the three options only. So I guess I have been locked out by previously changing the permission. What shall I do now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the folder in question and right click, select properties and open the security tab.

(I'm on XP here, but it should be similar in W7) From here, click Advanced and then select the Owner tab. Ensure your name is selected and then click Apply... This should then give you the right to undo the changes (although there may be a wait).

Comment: Remember, this was your only life line. if you lock out again, it will be more dificult to resolve.

Comment: Thanks! Why "if you lock out again, it will be more dificult to resolve"?